# Swift 3 - Changing background colour of all view controllers, via switch(Dark mode/Night mode)

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, swift3, viewcontroller

i crated a switch that lets the user change the background colour (dark mode). This only works on the view controller that the code is linked with. How would i set it so when the switch is activated to either dark or light mode, every view controller in my application would change, not just the one. Heres my code:

```
import UIKit
```

class DarkMode: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var DarkSwitch: UISwitch!


@IBOutlet var LightSwitch: UISwitch!

var DarkisOn = Bool()
var LightisOn = Bool()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let DarkDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    DarkisOn = DarkDefault.bool(forKey: "DarkDefault")




    let LightDefault = UserDefaults.standard

    LightisOn = LightDefault.bool(forKey: "LightDefault")



    if (DarkisOn == true) {

        DarkSwitch.isOn = true
        LightSwitch.isOn = false
        //run dark theme
        DarkTheme()


    }


    if (LightisOn == true) {

        DarkSwitch.isOn = false
        LightSwitch.isOn = true
        //run light theme
        LightTheme()




    }       



}


  func DarkTheme()    //dark colour
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)





}

 func LightTheme()   //light colour
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

}




@IBAction func DarkAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    DarkSwitch.isOn = true
    LightSwitch.isOn = false

    //run dark theme func
    DarkTheme()

    let DarkDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    DarkDefault.set(true, forKey: "DarkDefault")

    let LightDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    LightDefault.set(false, forKey: "LightDefault")


}



@IBAction func LightAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    DarkSwitch.isOn = false
    LightSwitch.isOn = true

    //run light theme func
    LightTheme()

    let DarkDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    DarkDefault.set(false, forKey: "DarkDefault")

    let LightDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    LightDefault.set(true, forKey: "LightDefault")


}
```

}

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to subclass them all from one that overrides viewDidLoad, with code like this.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156036/uiappearance-tutorial-getting-started) might help you.

Comment: For the love of God, please read a style guide. I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Oscar Apeland - Im just starting out you, you elitist weirdo. How can I learn if i don't ask questions... 'for the love of god' if you have nothing to say about my question, do one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base class like this (This is something I have used.)

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = MainColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]//user global variable

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black //user global variable
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white //user global variable
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Setup all your theme here.
All the color value should be global which you can change from another ViewController.

And now declare your all ViewControllers like this

```
class HomeViewController: BaseViewController {

}
```

This way HomeViewController will have all the appearance you set in BaseViewController.

Now All you have to do is change those global variables for color value.

Answer (score 1):

For one of my projects I created a class that controlled the UI colour scheme across all my ViewControllers.

```
class UIColourScheme {
    func set(for viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = bgColour
        ...
    }
    var bgColour = UIColor.black 
    static let instance = UIColourScheme()
}
```

I would then call this function in viewDidLoad() for every ViewController

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        UIColourScheme.instance.set(for:self)
    }
}
```

My colour scheme class setup colours for everything but it could be simplified to just the background colour as above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
protocol colorable {
   func setcolor(color: UIColor)
}
class HomeVC: colorable {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified `viewWillAppear` method. And added dark mode based on the time of the day.
You do not need to format the time/hours you receive back you may wanna use it as is in conditional statement.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    // get time of the day
    let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
    print(hour)

    if hour >= 14 {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
    else {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }

}
```